# MySQL performance 5.7 vs 8.0

Tags: mysql, performance

I've been testing the performance between 5.7 and 8.0.
We figured out that our application is around 30% slower with 8.0, so I tried to narrow down the issue.
I've started running simple sysbench tests and they showed the same perf hit.
Then I found this [nice article](https://severalnines.com/database-blog/mysql-performance-benchmarking-mysql-57-vs-mysql-80).

I tried to replicate the setup (4 cores, NVMe backend, only VM on the host, etc) the best I can.
I used two separate VMs based on CentOS 7 with community editions.
However, after tests I got the same ~30% perf hit with the [same scripts](https://github.com/geekgogie/mysql57_vs_8-benchmark_scripts) found in the blog post.
Then I tried to add the my.cnf options mentioned in the blog, nothing. Apart from these options, my.cnf was left as default (except innodb_buffer_pool, which was set to 8G from the start and binlogs were disabled on both).
As a last resort I just tried a simple sysbench run (removed all the extra options, ran it for 10 minutes), same thing.
I even tried to force M8 to use latin1 instead of utf8 (while creating the DB), which yielded these (best) results:
[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdPst.png)

Everything points to M8 having way less performance as M5.7, which contradicts ALL google listing.

Does anyone have any idea where the perf hit comes from?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the slowlog turned on?

Comment: No, its turned off. However, as its running generic queries as part of sysbench lua script, it doesnt really matter.

Answer (score 2):

8.0 implements ROLLBACK for DDL statements such as CREATE/DROP/ALTER TABLE/DATABASE/COLUMN.  This makes them slower.

For most applications, this is not a performance problem because DDL is only a rare event.  Are you doing a lot of DDL statements?

Comment: Sysbench runs in two parts:
- prepare (create tables, so DDL)
- run (runs the lua script as you want with whatever parameters, etc)

The preparation indeed took longer on M8, but what im concerned about is the run portion. The run does not do any DDL event. Please refer to the mentioned blogpost for more information about the test.

Comment: Sorry, but I work better with `CREATE TABLEs` and queries.  I don't see them in that GIT.  I am hoping to spot something else that might be inherently slower in 8.0 to explain the degredation.

Comment: As you can see the script does a lot of queries and thats where the problem lies. In the attached picture ([Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdPst.png)) there are no DDL (aka `CREATE TABLEs`), just selects, inserts, updates. You can check the lua script [here](https://github.com/akopytov/sysbench/blob/master/src/lua/oltp_read_write.lua)

Comment: I am suspicious of those traphs.  (1) I rarely seeing anyone with Threads_running more than 20, and probably never above 64.  So, bragging about things above 64 seems useless. (2) Above 64, TPS flattens then droops.  Guess what; that the latency is going through the roof!  This is where people reach for the Restart button.  (3)  I have trouble believing that double the number of connections can read _more than_ double the number of rows.

Comment: So, when you try to replicate the results, focus _below_ 64 connections.

Comment: Hey,

I replicated these results like 20 times on different envs.
I have my own old R510 for "homelab" (as stated, there were no other running VMs, it was also hosted on an NVMe drive for fun), I also tried it on our companys test servers, etc. Same result each time.

Comment: If it were easy, this post wouldn't exists :)